# he said with a resigned air

Tags: comprehension

Example with [a context](http://news.yahoo.com/ex-soviet-moldova-feels-squeeze-russian-fruit-embargo-051122817.html):

> "We, the Moldovans, have always been at a junction between different interests and have always suffered from this. It's our fate," he said **with a resigned air**.

I know what *resigned* means—it is when you unwillingly accept something you're not really happy about. The only thing that I have a problem with is how should I understand *an air* in this context?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the context of that quote, *air* has the meaning of:

> - [2. an impression of a quality or manner given by someone or something](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=air+definition)

So we could rephrase "...he said **with a resigned air**" as "...he said **in a resigned manner**."

In other words, the speaker says, "We, the Moldovans have always been... It's our fate," in a way that indicates his feeling/attitude of [resignation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/resignation).